# Sendgrid template CSS is ignored

Tags: css, sendgrid, email-templates

I have used Sendgrid to make the following template:

[image]

To send this using my Node server I have created the following module:

```
/**
 * Created by root on 6/6/16.
 */
var path = require('path'),
    emailTemplates = require('email-templates'),
    async = require("async"),
    mailConfig = require('../config/email.json'),
    templates = require('../config/emailTemplates.json'),
    _ = require('lodash'),
    sendgrid = require('sendgrid')(mailConfig.sendGridApiKey);
var mymailer = {};


    /**
     * Sends an email to either one or multiple users
     * @param template_id (The id key of the template. Can be found in emailTemplates.json
     * @param to String or Array
     * @param from String
     * @param subject String
     * @param keyReplacer Array of objects for keys to replace in the template
     */
    mymailer.sendTemplate = function (template_id, to, from, subject, keyReplacer, text) {
        var email = new sendgrid.Email();
        var templateKey = templates[template_id];
        if (templateKey) {
            email.setSmtpapiTos(to);
            email.subject = subject;
            email.from = from;
            email.text = text;
            email.html = '';
            email.setFilters({
                'templates': {
                    'settings': {
                        'enable': 1,
                        'template_id': templateKey
                    }
                }
            });
            email.smtpapi.header.sub = createSub(keyReplacer);
            sendgrid.send(email);
        }
        else {
            console.log('incorrect key');
        }
    };
    
    function createSub(keyReplacer) {
        var finalObject = {};
        if (keyReplacer) {
            _.forEach(keyReplacer, function (value, key) {
                var k = ':' + key;
                finalObject[k] = [value];
            })
        }
        return finalObject;
    }
    

module.exports = mymailer;
```

However when I receive my email it is stripped from both CSS and images.

It looks like this:

[image]

I guess it's some settings I'm missing but I don't know which. Which ones can I try?

**Template html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-dnd="true">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
  <!--[if !mso]><!-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
  <!--<![endif]-->

  <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]><style type="text/css">
  table {border-collapse: collapse;}
  table, td {mso-table-lspace: 0pt;mso-table-rspace: 0pt;}
  img {-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    color: #000000;
  }
  body a {
    color: #0071cb;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  p { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
  table[class="wrapper"] {
    width:100% !important;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  img[class="max-width"] {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .preheader .rightColumnContent,
    .footer .rightColumnContent {
        text-align: left !important;
    }
    .preheader .rightColumnContent div,
    .preheader .rightColumnContent span,
    .footer .rightColumnContent div,
    .footer .rightColumnContent span {
      text-align: left !important;
    }
    .preheader .rightColumnContent,
    .preheader .leftColumnContent {
      font-size: 80% !important;
      padding: 5px 0;
    }
    table[class="wrapper-mobile"] {
      width: 100% !important;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    img[class="max-width"] {
      height: auto !important;
    }
    a[class="bulletproof-button"] {
      display: block !important;
      width: auto !important;
      font-size: 80%;
      padding-left: 0 !important;
      padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
    // 2 columns
    #templateColumns{
        width:100% !important;
    }

    .templateColumnContainer{
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
        padding-left: 0 !important;
        padding-right: 0 !important;
    }
  }
  </style>
  <style>
  body, p, div { font-family: arial,sans-serif; }
</style>
  <style>
  body, p, div { font-size: 14px; }
</style>
</head>
<body yahoofix="true" style="min-width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; font-size: 14px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; color: #000000; background-color: #0071CB; color: #000000;" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22bodybackground%22%3A%22%230071CB%22%2C%22bodyfontname%22%3A%22arial%2Csans-serif%22%2C%22bodytextcolor%22%3A%22%23000000%22%2C%22bodylinkcolor%22%3A%22%230071cb%22%2C%22bodyfontsize%22%3A14%7D'>
  <center class="wrapper">
    <div class="webkit">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#0071CB">
      <tr><td valign="top" bgcolor="#0071CB" width="100%">
      <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
          <![endif]-->
            <table width="100%" role="content-container" class="outer" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22containerpadding%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22containerwidth%22%3A600%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%23FFFFFF%22%7D' align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="100%"><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                      <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <![endif]-->
                              <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width: 100%; max-width:600px;" align="center">
                                <tr><td role="modules-container" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; color: #000000; text-align: left;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" align="left">
                                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" style="display:none !important; visibility:hidden; opacity:0; color:transparent; height:0; width:0;" class="module preheader preheader-hide" role="module" data-type="preheader">
  <tr><td role="module-content"><p></p></td></tr>
</table>
<table class="module" role="module" data-type="wysiwyg" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22padding%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D'>
<tr><td role="module-content" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" bgcolor="#ffffff"><div>&lt;%body%&gt;</div></td></tr></table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" class="module wrapper" role="module" data-type="imagetext" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22imagebackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22imagemargin%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22textbackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22textmargin%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22imagealignment%22%3A%22left%22%7D'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr role="module-content">
          <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" height="100%" class="templateColumnContainer"  bgcolor="#ffffff" >
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
              <tr>
                <td class="leftColumnContent" role="column-one" height="100%" style="height:100%;width:50%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><table role="module" data-type="image" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" class="wrapper" data-attributes='%7B%22child%22%3Atrue%2C%22link%22%3A%22%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22250%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22333%22%2C%22imagebackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22https%3A//marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/e4f73dd0d8cd27c174bae4dce1f04e4db74721c83cfd297559428dceb682cd79f2b565aa0bcacfb7175b27be1b4d5d10f112847379aa271aeb56760ad33e36c3.jpg%22%2C%22alt_text%22%3A%22%22%2C%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22imagemargin%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22%22%2C%22responsive%22%3Afalse%7D'>
<tr>
  <td style="font-size:6px;line-height:10px;background-color:#ffffff;padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" valign="top" align="" role="module-content">

  <img class="max-width"  width="250"   height="333"  src="https://marketing-image-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/e4f73dd0d8cd27c174bae4dce1f04e4db74721c83cfd297559428dceb682cd79f2b565aa0bcacfb7175b27be1b4d5d10f112847379aa271aeb56760ad33e36c3.jpg" alt="" border="0" style="display: block; color: #000; text-decoration: none; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; " />

</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
          <td align="center" valign="top" width="50%" height="100%" class="templateColumnContainer"  bgcolor="#ffffff" >
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
              <tr>
                <td class="rightColumnContent" role="column-two" height="100%" style="height:100%;width:50%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;"><table class="module" role="module" data-type="text" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22child%22%3Atrue%2C%22padding%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D'>
<tr>
  <td role="module-content"  valign="top" height="100%" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" bgcolor="#ffffff"><div>Hello world</div> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" role="module" data-type="columns" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22columns%22%3A2%2C%22padding%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22cellpadding%22%3A0%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%22%7D'>
  <tr><td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" bgcolor="">
    <table class="columns--container-table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
      <tr role="module-content">
        <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px" role="column-0" align="center" valign="top" width="50%" height="100%" class="templateColumnContainer column-drop-area empty">
  
</td><td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px" role="column-1" align="center" valign="top" width="50%" height="100%" class="templateColumnContainer column-drop-area ">
  <table class="module" role="module" data-type="button" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22borderradius%22%3A6%2C%22buttonpadding%22%3A%2212%2C18%2C12%2C18%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Your%20Bulletproof%20Button%22%2C%22alignment%22%3A%22center%22%2C%22fontsize%22%3A16%2C%22url%22%3A%22%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22%22%2C%22width%22%3A%22%22%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22padding%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22buttoncolor%22%3A%22%231188e6%22%2C%22textcolor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22bordercolor%22%3A%22%231288e5%22%7D'>
<tr>
  <td style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper-mobile">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="-webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; font-size: 16px;" bgcolor="#1188e6">
          <a href="" class="bulletproof-button" target="_blank" style="height: px; width: px; font-size: 16px; line-height: px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; padding: 12px 18px 12px 18px; text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #1288e5; display: inline-block;">Your Bulletproof Button</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>

</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%" class="module footer" role="module" data-type="footer" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22columns%22%3A1%2C%22padding%22%3A%2210%2C5%2C10%2C5%22%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D'>
  <tr><td style="padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" width="100%">
      <tr role="module-content">
        
        <td align="center" valign="top" width="100%" height="100%" class="templateColumnContainer">
          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <tr>
              <td class="leftColumnContent" role="column-one" height="100%" style="height:100%;"><table class="module" role="module" data-type="text" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  width="100%" style="table-layout: fixed;" data-attributes='%7B%22dropped%22%3Atrue%2C%22child%22%3Afalse%2C%22padding%22%3A%220%2C0%2C0%2C0%22%2C%22containerbackground%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D'>
<tr>
  <td role="module-content"  valign="top" height="100%" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" bgcolor="#ffffff"><div style="font-size:12px;line-height:150%;margin:0;text-align:center;">
  This email was sent by: [Sender_Name] [Sender_Address], [Sender_City] [Sender_State] [Sender_Zip]
</div>
<div style="font-size:12px;line-height:150%;margin:0;text-align:center;">
  To unsubscribe click: <a href="[Unsubscribe]">here</a>
</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td></tr>
</table>

                                </tr></td>
                              </table>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                          </td>
                        </td>
                      </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
      </tr></td>
      </table>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JSYK email clients dont read separated css file, it must be inline css.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is, email clients does not support embedded css. Therefore all styles that you need must be inline with the tag. Also ugly as it might be, but the best way to layout an email template is by using tables.

However, here are some things that might help you with this problem.

**TIPS**

This will not work:

```
<style media="screen">
    h1{
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<h1>I like turtles</h1>
```

This will work:

```
<h1 style="color:red;">I like turtles</h1>
```

**HELPFUL SOURCES**

You can read this to know more about creating email templates.

1. [Source 1](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps)
2. [Source 2](http://foundation.zurb.com/)

Also, there are some **inliner** out there that will convert your embedded css to inline css. Personally I am using [Zurb's email inliner](http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html) to solve this problem.

That's all I can say, I hope this will get you somewhere. Good luck :)

Comment: Can i ask why sendgrids builder makes the css like that then? if you know ofcourse :)

Comment: It's not the send grid builder that's doing that, it's the email client itself :) @MarcRasmussen

Comment: But using the builder it creates the above html

Comment: @MarcRasmussen If you think my answer helped you or if it was useful to you, you can mark it right so others will know that this is a reliable answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, I fixed it by changing

```
 Content content = new Content("text/plain", notification.getContent());
```

To

```
  Content content = new Content("text/html", notification.getContent());
```